# Is it possible to convert .ahk to .lua?

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I want to make a simple macro in LUA to Logitech mouse. I am complete novice and I just pasted few lines together from few sources. First of all, it looks like a mess but kind of works, sorry about it I am complete novice to it. Now the problems I am having, is that;

What I'm trying to accomplish is when I press whatever key I assign this to, it will toggle this script to be looped/repeat until I press whatever key again.

I want to be able to press CTRL+7 on my mouse and toggle repeat on, until I press CTRL+7 again to turn the repeat off.

Please help. Thank you for your time.

```
OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == nil then
   repeat
      MoveMouseRelative(1280,-5000)
      PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
      Sleep(3200)
until not IsMouseButtonPressed(nil)
end
end
```

Comment: LGS/GHUB is unable to monitor alpha (A-Z) and digit (0-9) keys on the keyboard.  This is done intentionally to prohibit writing keyloggers in LGS.  Only mouse buttons on Logitech mouse (and G1,G2,... keys on Logitech keyboards) can be handled by Lua script.  So, AHK has more capabilities.

Comment: Arguments for `MoveMouseRelative` must be in the range `-127..+127`

Comment: Mr. Egor can I simply use G7? but as I mentioned before can it be looped?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.**
Do you use Mouse Button 4 ("back") in the game?

- If YES (some action is set to MB#4 in the game), proceed to "Step 2".
- If NO (the game ignores MB#4 press), skip "Step 2" and proceed to "Step 3".

---

**Step 2.**
You have to remap game action from MB#4 to some other key.
Do the following:

- choose keyboard key you don't currently use in the game
  (let's assume the `F12` key is not currently used)
- go to GHUB (mouse device, "Assignments" screen, KEYS tab);
  assign `F12` to your physical MB#4
- go to your game settings;
  set the game action to `F12` instead of MB#4

Now when you press physical MB#4, the game receives `F12` and activates the game action.
Skip "Step 3" and proceed to "Step 4".

---

**Step 3.**
Go to GHUB (mouse device, "Assignments" screen).
Unassign standard command "Back" from physical MB#4 (click and select DISABLE from the drop-down menu).
Disabled MB#4 will look like a white circle with black inside.

---

**Step 4.**
Go to GHUB (keyboard device, "Assignments" screen).
Assign standard command "Back" to physical key G7.

---

**Step 5.**
Set the script:

```
local toggle, prev_down

local function Interruptable_Sleep(ms)
   local tm = GetRunningTime() + ms
   repeat
      local now = GetRunningTime()
      if now < tm then
         Sleep(math.min(10, tm - now))
         local down = IsMouseButtonPressed(4)  -- 4 = "Back"
         toggle, prev_down = toggle or not prev_down and down, down
      end
   until toggle or now >= tm
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
   if event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 7 then
      toggle = not toggle
      if toggle then
         prev_down, toggle = true
         repeat
            for j = 1, 40 do
               MoveMouseRelative(1280/40,-5000/40)
               Interruptable_Sleep(10)
            end
            if not toggle then 
               PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
               Interruptable_Sleep(3200)
            end
         until toggle
      end
   end
end
```

Now you can start and stop the loop by pressing keyboard key G7